# How to display object age Histogram for a Java process

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I would like to view the object age histogram for a Java heap. Something like the one referenced by [this page](http://insightfullogic.com/2013/Feb/20/garbage-collection-java-1/).

[image: Histogram of Java object lifespan]

I intend to use this information to configure better the Java garbage collector.

Comment: `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution`

Comment: `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution ` shows only survivor space "histogram". Nothing about OldGen or Eden. It is also calculated at minor GCs.

Comment: The JVM does not track that information on a per-object basis because it does not use that information in the old gen. Some profilers with allocation recording may provide an approximation of this kind of information if you take snapshots at regular intervals.